# gives error when SET variable in SELECT environment in SQL Server 2019

Tags: select, sql-server-2019

In the company where I work, many products are produced with names **CODE1**, **CODE2**, etc.

I have to write the function related to the "*production cost*" of these products.

Each **IF** section in code bellow corresponds to a product. Parameters **[COL1]**, **[CostOfpi1]** are read from a table named **MainTable**, but since it is not possible to use **SET** in the **SELECT** environment, the corresponding code gives an error. How can I solve this problem?

```
SELECT
--------------------------------
        SET @area1 = @aa * @bb;
        SET @PiProd1 = [COL1];
--------------------------------
        SET @area2 = 2 * @aa * @bb;
        SET @PiProd2 = [CostOfpi1];
FROM MyTables;
```

Comment: Please show the full code for your function, as your current code is missing declarations etc, as well as table definitions

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `SET`, you can just `SELECT` directly into the variable like this generally:

```
SELECT
    @C1 = 2500,
    @C2 = 1480.122342
```

But looking at your code is this a scalar function? Depending on the answer, you may even just be able to `SET` them directly without the `SELECT`.

> the corresponding code gives an error

You should provide that error message in your original Post. There's a lot of odd pieces of your code that are also incorrect / broken that I think you're going to run into issues with such as the random `FROM MyTables` at the end of the function before the `RETURN` clause.

---

Also just a disclaimer that scalar and multi-statement table valued functions are not great for performance and prevent any consumers from being able to use parallelism in their execution.

Comment: I edit the post, maybe my question is clearer. My goal is to use parameters [COL1], [CostOfpi1] to set various variables. How should I write the code when I want to use these parameters to assign values to different variables and take parameters [COL1], [CostOfpi1] from the "Mytables" at the same time? These parameters have been used many times in the text of the code and it is not possible to write a select for each of them.